# How to place dynamic templates in elk instead of using dev tools in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, kibana-5

I'm new to ELK can any one help me. I'm able to get query results by placing following in dev tools of Kibana. But I need to load this template dynamically instead of querying from dev tools.

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "obj1" : {
                    "type" : "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in configuring this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not creating a json file with your template and push it with curl?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) if you want to set the mapping at index creation time.  You can use the ES dev tools to set that up so that it matches by name.  For example:

```
PUT _template/my_index
{
  "template": "my_index*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "obj1" : {
                "type" : "nested"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is especially needed for time-based indexes.

If you are just looking for a tool, use curl:

```
curl -XPUT http://your_cluster:9200/index -d '{your json here}'
```

You can script the insert of the template in the same way if needed